# Why is the result of Array(1,2,3).toString() different each time it is executed and how is the result determined?

Tags: java, scala

I know that I can get my desired output by using Array(1,2,3).mkString(",") but I want to know why/how the resulting values are determined when .toString() is used instead.

Comment: `return this.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(this.hashCode());` is the code Java (and Scala) use when you invoke `toString()` on an object.

Comment: The thing is that a **Scala** `Array` is really a **Java** `Array`. And the `toString` of that is the one explained by jrook. `Lists` and other **Scala** data structures, implement `toString` in terms of `mkString`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not different each time. It is unique to the specific Array instance:

```
scala> val a = Array(1,2,3)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> a.toString()
res2: String = [I@40499e4f

scala> a.toString()
res3: String = [I@40499e4f
```

Creating a new array changes the result.

```
scala> Array(1,2,3).toString()
res4: String = [I@7dd712e8
```

The string `[I@40499e4f` has two parts: the Array class name and the hash code (`CLASS_NAME@HASH_CODE`)

- `[` the object is a Java array.
- `I` Signifies that this is an Array of Integer (Java primitive)
- `@` (just separates the array description)
- `40499e4f` This is the `.hashCode()` for that Java object.

**What is the hash code**
It's a bit complicated. It's sort of like an "object ID" for the Java instance, but it's not necessarily unique. The main point of the hash code is to tell you whether or not two objects are "equal" to each other.

For example:

```
scala> case class MyClass(a: Int)
defined class MyClass

scala> val b = MyClass(2)
b: MyClass = MyClass(2)

scala> val c = MyClass(3)
c: MyClass = MyClass(3)

scala> val d = MyClass(3)
d: MyClass = MyClass(3)

scala> b.hashCode()
res5: Int = 369114374

scala> c.hashCode()
res6: Int = 937862449

scala> d.hashCode()
res7: Int = 937862449

scala> d == c
res8: Boolean = true

scala> c == b
res9: Boolean = false
```

You can see that `c` and `d` have the same hashCode(), even though they are actually different Java object instances.

Comment: "`[I` This is the Java class name for java.util.Array" There is no class named `Array` in the `java.util` package. Java's array classes aren't defined anywhere in the standard library - they're magic.

Answer (score 0):

It's additional info to @robert 's answer.

From Javadoc of [`Object#hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--):

> If two objects are equal according to the **`equals(Object)`**
>           method, then calling the **hashCode** method on each of
>           the two objects must produce the same integer result.
>
> As much as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by 
>   class `Object` does return distinct integers for distinct
>        objects. (**This is typically implemented by converting the internal
>         address of the object into an integer**, but this implementation
>         technique is not required by the
>         Java™ programming language.)

`java.util.Arrays` has method `equals`. `Arrays.equals(a,b)` means *for each `i` from 0 untill `max(a.length, b.length)` `a(i) == b(i)`*.

But `a.equals(b)` means *link to `a` and link to `b` are equal*, according to `Object#equals`.